# Google is Crawling my url but the crawled page is the old version

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, meta-description

Google is constantly crawling my site as it is constantly updated but the `title` tag and meta description are not updated in the SERP results.

So, I checked the crawled page and it is not crawling the updated content but the old content. I have updated the content and forced a recrawl it but from where did they find the old Content? It's been over 2 weeks.

Screenshot of the crawled page:

[image: Crawled page showing version 6.11]

but the updated version is 6.12

Comment: Have you done a `site:yoururl.com` query and checked the cached copy of your page there, to see whether their cache contains the updated code including the new title and meta desc? Google often adjusts what it displays in SERPs based on the query, it does not always use your defined title and meta description.

Comment: Just because Google has crawled to get the newest title and meta description, it may still choose to use the old one.   See [Why would Google show the old title when it has indexed the page with a new title?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/103436/why-would-google-show-the-old-title-when-it-has-indexed-the-page-with-a-new-titl)

Comment: Are you using a CDN? does your server cache URLs?

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to judge without more information. There could be a CDN in the way you need to flush. Your cache headers might be causing Google to cache results. I would also make sure no meta tags or "canonical" tags are in the body. A test for these issues could be.

```
curl -v https://example.com/yourpage
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need have a waite. It will show the exact title and description when you *site:yoururl.com*. Sometimes, Google will not follow your discription, then choose some content it thinks the best