# Why google crawler indexes old data of the website?

Tags: seo, googlebot, search-engine-indexing, search-engines

A month ago I updated the website with a new Title and Description (basically the whole website had been changed) but the Google crawler doesn't index these new data and continues to show the old one. 
 
I checked it in the Google Search Console and found a very strange behavior. In the **URL inspection** tab I saw that the last indexing was a few days ago (21 Jan 2021) by a mobile crawler and in the Crawled page report old data is showing. So the bot found the old data somehow.
When I used the **TEST LIVE URL** tab I found that the crawler picked up the new data.
How it's possible and how to make the standard indexing tool to see the relevant data?

I manually requested the re-indexing process, however, I'm not sure it helps because the last index was a few days ago and the site  had been changed a month ago

P.S. I don't have the `robots.txt` file. Bing shows the same old data.
Maybe I should remove the URL indexing at all and request the new re-indexing?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Are you sure the mobile crawler was Googles?  You say you changed the description?  Are you referring to the meta tags?  If so, Google doesn't necessarily use meta tags for description anymore.Additionally, you should not expect the last crawl to immediately update the SERPS immediately.  Only if Google's algorithm considers the content new, does it update the search results, and then it may be several weeks to a month before the changes will be reflected in the SERPs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why would Google show the old title when it has indexed the page with a new title?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/103436/why-would-google-show-the-old-title-when-it-has-indexed-the-page-with-a-new-titl)

Comment: Hi Trebor. Thanks for the answer. Yes, it's the google crawler because I saw it in the Google Search Engine report. I can provide a screenshot if needed. I changed the Title and the meta tag Description because this data shows in the Google Search Results so I wanted to change it. I did it more than 1 month ago however any search engine (Bing, Google, DDG) doesn't update this data and I don't understand why. That's why I checked the Google Search Engine and saw that the TEST LIVE URL - shows the updated data but the URL inspention - doesn't. So could you, please, give some suggestion about it?