# Why my website description and title not showing on google?

Tags: wordpress, seo, web-hosting, yoast

When I search my website on google It shows the domain description and title. Why my own title description and domain are not showing?

You can see the second link its show my website description and title but first link is not showing.

[image: Here is the image you can see it clearly.]

Comment: Can't read the URL, I would check the META data in the <head> segment of your main index page.  The title and description are just not right.  Otherwise, use webmasters to force google to update their index for your main page if it has been updated but cached an early copy of your site.

Comment: See also [Why would Google show the old title when it has indexed the page with a new title?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/103436/why-would-google-show-the-old-title-when-it-has-indexed-the-page-with-a-new-titl)

Answer (score 0):

How long has your website been up?

It looks like Google hasn't re-crawled it yet since you put up the website. It's still showing the title and description from the domain broker who apparently held the domain name before you put up your site.

Solutions are to (1) wait until Google automatically re-crawls your page, or (2) use Google Search Console to manually trigger a re-crawl.